# Does CQL3 "IF" make my update not idempotent?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.2

It seems to me that using IF would make the statement possibly fail if re-tried.  Therefore, the statement is not idempotent.  For instance, given the CQL below, if it fails because of a timeout or system problem and I retry it, then it may not work because another person may have updated the version between retries.

```
UPDATE users
SET name = 'foo', version = 4
WHERE userid = 1
IF version = 3
```

Best practices for updates in Cassandra are to make updates idempotent, yet the IF operator is in direct opposition to this.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If your application is idempotent, then generally you wouldn't need to use the expensive IF clause, since all your clients would be trying to set the same value.

For example, suppose your clients were aggregating some values and writing the result to a roll up table. Each client would calculate the same total and write the same value, so it wouldn't matter if multiple clients wrote to it, or what order they wrote to it, since it would be the same value.

If what you are actually looking for is mutual exclusion, such as keeping a bank balance, then the IF clause could be used. You might read a row to get the current balance, then subtract some money and update the balance only if the balance hadn't changed since you read it. If another client was trying to add a deposit at the same time, then it would fail and would have to try again.

But another way to do that without mutual exclusion is to write each withdrawal and deposit as a separate clustered transaction row, and then calculate the balance as an idempotent result of applying all the transaction rows.

You can use the IF clause for idempotent writes, but it seems pointless.  The first client to do the write would succeed and Cassandra would return the value "applied=True".  And the next client to try the same write would get back "applied=False, version=4", indicating that the row had already been updated to version 4 so nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1):

This question is more about linerizability(ordering) than idempotency I think. This query uses Paxos to try to determine the state of the system before applying a change. If the state of the system is identical then the query can be retried many times without a change in the results. This provides a weak form of ordering (and is expensive) unlike most Cassandra writes. Generally you should only use CAS operations if you are attempting to record state of a system (rather than a history or log)

Do not use many of these queries if you can help it, the guidelines suggest having only a small percentage of your queries rely on this behavior.